# Is there an in-universe reason Harry says this or is this simply a Rowling mistake?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Order of the Phoenix*, after

> Sirius dies,

Harry, sitting in Dumbledore's office, thinks:

> Harry turned his back on Dumbledore and stared determinedly out of the window. He could see the Quidditch stadium in the distance. **Sirius had appeared there once, disguised as the shaggy black dog, so he could watch Harry play…** **he had probably come to see whether Harry was as good as James had been… Harry had never asked him…**

However, in *Prisoner of Azkaban* when they are in the Shrieking Shack, Sirius says:

> I swam as a dog back to the mainland… I journeyed north and
>   slipped into the Hogwarts grounds as a dog. I’ve been living in the forest ever since, **except when I came to watch the Quidditch, of course. You fly as well as your father did, Harry…**

Sirius already told Harry that he flew as well as James, so the first quote seems like an odd thing for Harry to say. Is there a reason for this or did Rowling simply make a mistake?

Comment: In the second quote Sirius just states the fact. He doesn't say that that's why he came, nor did Harry ask him why he came. So technically the first quote is not inaccurate.

Comment: @Alex That's pretty facile.  Nobody regrets not asking a question they didn't have to ask.

Comment: @DavidW Knowing that Sirius thought he was as good as his father doesn’t equal knowing that seeking that information was what motivated Sirius to come.

Comment: I would argue it's just poor writing. It's good enough to end with the memory of him coming to watch Harry play - there's rarely one, single unifying purpose behind going to watch someone you care about play a sport - you're just going to watch them play. He compared him to his dad, yeah, but he wasn't being a talent scout. It was his god son, he just wanted to watch him play.

It just goes on a couple of phrases too long, people don't think like that. Just a lazy way to remind us that Harry lost his dad, first, and this is another new loss.

Comment: Maybe the second (earlier) quote is grounds for Harry to hypothesize "he had probably come to see whether Harry was as good as James had been."

Comment: Ahem, he... _forgot_.

Comment: The explicit idea here is that we the readers know, but sadly with everything going on, Harry doesn't remember this loving detail about Sirius...

Comment: It isn't poor writing. I think the sentence is missing the word _just_. The fifth HP book is all about teen angst. He isn't just wondering Sirius, he is mourning, while also angry and confused. It isn't, "He had probably come to see whether Harry was as good as James had been." With the angst he is feeling, I always interpret the sentence as, "He had probably _just_ come to see whether Harry was as good as James had been". It is hinted multiple times in OOTP that Sirius treats Harry like James, not like his own person. Harry may be feeling he lost his godfather, but Sirius didn't lose him.

Answer (score 103):

I have another interpretation of this passage:

It's not that Harry had never asked Sirius, whether he was as good as his father in Quidditch.

Imho this sentence means: He never asked Sirius WHY he was there in the first place.

> he had **probably come to see** whether Harry was as good as James had been
>
> Harry had never asked him…

So the uncertainty does not lie on the question, if Harry was as good as his father, but on the question, why Sirius had watched the match.

In that case the two passages do not contradict each other...

Comment: He was there to watch the Quidditch. Why else would someone go to a Quidditch match?

Comment: @GreySage That's the question:  Did he go to watch the Quidditch Match (perhaps for nostalgia?), or was he there to watch **Harry**?

Comment: @Chronocidal Of course he was there to watch Harry. Watching Quidditch can be fun, but it's not worth the risk to be caught. (Quidditch fanatics like Oliver Wood may disagree.)

Comment: @QuestionAuthority and even if we assume that he was there to watch Harry (which is likely though not totally certain from the quote), that wouldn't mean self-doubting Harry comes automatically to the same conclusion! In particular, since at that point they hadn't met, yet and their first encounter was everything but smooth. He might also wonder whether Sirius wanted to compare him to his father, perhaps also whether Sirius really took the risk just for him or whether he wanted to look out for that little ratty guy etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes little sense.

Comment: Perhaps the uncertainty goes a little further, into whether Sirius cares *about* how similar he is to his father, inasmuch as he cares *because* of how similar he is or seemed to be, or if he did, would, or could care about Harry for himself even when he shows he is different, as he inevitably will.

Comment: @QuestionAuthority The next question then is...  How did Sirius Black, escaped inmate extraordinaire, **know** that Harry Potter played Quidditch?  Unless that *also* made it to a copy of the Daily Prophet during Harry's first year that Sirius just happened to read?

Comment: @Chronocidal Crookshanks probably told him

Comment: There is the cultural thing that in the UK it’s relatively uncommon for people who are not directly involved in a school sports match, pupils, staff or parents to come and watch a game. We don’t make a big social event of school sports in the same way some other countries do. For a British child, particularly one of Harry’s muggle,  comprehensive school upbringing before he came to Hogwarts the idea that someone outside of the school would to come and watch would be a little strange.

Comment: This is a gramatically possible but a very unplausible explanation.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, I think follow up comments may have been a bit confused. It's not _was Sirius there to watch quidditch_, or _Harry_. The question is, in my mind, Was Sirius there out of love for Harry, or for love of James? Did Sirius care about the present with Harry, or was he living in the past with James? This is brought forward earlier in OOTP when Molly says that Sirius is acting like he has his best friend. "He's just a boy, Sirius. He's not James." At the time Harry is okay being treated like James, but maybe at this point he's sad they never had a proper life together.

Answer (score 63):

The most likely in-universe explanation is that Harry doesn't remember the second quote, as it is two years ago for him, and he was just fighting for his life and lost Sirius.

The most likely out-of-universe explanation is that Rowling doesn't remember the second quote, as it is more than two years between the books.

The comment by [Alex](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/100430/alex) that the two statements don't contradict each other is technically true, but it is a subtle difference that does't fit Harry's character. If Harry remembers the second quote then his thoughts would be like "I know Sirius thinks I fly as well as my father, but was that the reasons why he came to watch the Quidditch?" It implies that Harry thinks people need a reason to watch Quidditch and that he wants to be compared to his father.

Comment: I believe this is the most correct answer, as it's the only one which doesn't rely on pedantic nitpicking of the passages in question, instead relying on the entirely reasonable notion that a character simply forgot a throwaway line from two years before.

Answer (score 27):

What Harry never asked Sirius was whether Harry *played Quidditch* as well as James did.  Sirius only said that Harry flew as well as James, not that he played Quidditch as well as James.

Broomstick skills are extremely important to Quidditch, of course, but it is possible to be a skilled flyer and still be only a mediocre player.

(One might reasonably question whether it is sensible to compare a Seeker with a Chaser, but that's a more subtle point unlikely to make much of an impression on a grieving teenager.)

Answer (score 2):

In my honest opinion when the first quote was said Harry didn't believe much of what Sirius was saying, because he didn't trust him at the moment, so these words didn't stick in Harry's mind and just got passed.

But may be it's just poor writing, yes. There are many things like this through the books. For example, in the first or second book there is a phrase about a cure for werewolf, but later the readers were introduced to the the fact that it is incurable.

Comment: How is it "poor writing" to have a character forget a throwaway remark after two years?

Comment: _in the first or second book there is a phrase about a cure for werewolf_. Citation needed. The only thing close to what you're describing I can remember is the Wagga Wagga Werewolf story which is made up by Lockhart.

Comment: @JulienLopez "Harry looked down at the pair of white rabbits he was supposed to be turning into slippers." Harry Potter and the chamber of secrets, chapter 16. The transfiguration of middle-sized animals with a spine is a too advanced magic for a second year student.